# Опциональные параметры процедуры MS SQL

Tags: c#, база-данных, .net, sql-server

Есть `SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd)` , который наполняет SQL-команду аргументами процедуры. Можно ли как-нибудь понять что опционально, а что нет ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак. `SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd)` [внутри](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlCommand.cs,faa7cb5d3974c14a) использует вызов хранимой процедуры `sp_procedure_params_100_managed` для получения списка параметров. А в результатах вызова `sp_procedure_params_100_managed` нет флага опциональности параметра.

Т.е. `DeriveParameters` ничего об опциональности параметров не знает и добавляет в команду все подряд.

Comment: И нет никаких других способов это узнать опциональность параметров? Например, если ручками в какой-нибудь системной таблице их посмотреть.

Comment: @iluxa1810 можно - вся информация лежит в [sys.parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176074.aspx). Вот пример выборки - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20115881/ - к нему нужно дописать выборку has_default_value

Comment: я думаю, что следует добавить в ответ, как альтернативный способ получения параметров.